# Create new activity while click the setting icon

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

If I click the `settings` icon,it have to create the new activity.But It shows the pop up search.Below I  am posted the codes and screenshot relevant to that.

[image]

[image]

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
       switch (item.getItemId()) 
       {
         case R.id.search:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
      //      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }
```

**main.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:title="@string/search"/>

</menu>
```

If I click that icon,the new activity have to created.But it shows the pop up window `search`.I didn't need that pop up window.simply it have to move to the new activity while click the setting icon.So far I done a code like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add in item tag

`android:showAsAction="always"`

Then no pop up is there.

Answer (score 2):

Change the xml to:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/search"/>
```

or you can also try android:showAsAction="always" as suggested by NAP.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `onOptionsItemSelected` but you are writing code for starting an activity in menu item `Seach`'s on click. Instead of that you will need to do it in `settings`'s click

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
   switch (item.getItemId()) 
   {
       case R.id.settings:
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           return true;
       default:
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But his `android:id="@+id/search"` is `search`? This question confuse me, his menu XML code should hide the `settings`, right?

Comment: @BlazeTama If I click the top right corner icon,then it have to create a new activity.But it shows pop up.